# What images are used by AKS/K8s service?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod, azure-container-registry, containerd

I was creating a service to cleanup cached/unused images from all the nodes in AKS clusters. The implementation uses "**crictl rmi --prune**", which deletes all the images which do not have an active pod/container running at the time of trigger i.e., all unused images in cache.

However, I was asked what happens if it deletes images which are required by AKS/K8s, which are currently not in use but might be needed in future? and what if its ImagePullPolicy is set to Never?

So, I had few questions for AKS/K8 experts:

- I want to know what images are used by AKS/K8s service and in what scenarios?
- What is the default ImagePullPolicy for images AKs/k8s might need? &
  How can I check if default ImagePullPolicy was changed?
- "crictl rmi --prune" is not a recommended way to cleanup cached/unused images? If not,
  what is the recommended way to cleanup cached images from
  cluster nodes?

Apologies if these questions sound silly, still a rookie with K8s :)

Thanks and Regards,

Junaid.

Answer (score 1):

That's the right way of cleaning up of old/cached images.
More details here:
https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1421

You can also use a DaemonSet YAML file which can clean-up automatically:
https://gist.github.com/alexeldeib/2a02ccb3db02ddb828a9c1ef04f2b955

/////////////

AKS runs it's images from mcr.microsoft.com repository for all the pods running in kube-system and by-default for those pods imagePullPolicy is "ifNotPresent" and you can't edit/change the policy of the system pods.

//////////

You can see all the pods and its image details in kube-system namespace

**Example:**

kubectl get pods -n kube-system

(pick up one of the pod from above output, here I am checking kube-proxy pods)

kubectl get pod kube-proxy-cwrqw -n kube-system -o yaml
(From the output you can search for ImagePullPolicy attribute value)